# How to send a firebase notification to android phone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, web-applications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make a web app that can send a firebase cloud messaging notification to my topic using JavaScript. Is there any good example code for this? Or can someone explain how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase docs are great and a good place to start, do you have any specific questions?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding a few things. 

1) What url do I send to? is it the one that has my project name in it or just the https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

2) What Authorization key do I use? Is it just my server key? Or my legacy key? I don't quite understand because it seems like you used to be able to do it with just the server key but some places say you need the OAuth 2.0 key.

3) I seem to kind of have it working, I get a message id response. But it doesn't appear on my android app, or in my console. How can I use the message id to maybe trace where it went?